# Acquiring information from image of a hand

Tags: java, image-processing

I am trying to make a small software which will take scanned image of human hand as input and will predict the future on the basis of principles of palmistry.
I would like to have a piece of advice on how can the coordinates of various lines on hand can be obtained accurately.
The approach should be kept generic as I don't have specific set of images, it should work with all the images.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at Hough Transforms

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the `java.lang.Palmistry` package, possibly combined with the `java.lang.FuturePrediction` package as well.

All jokes aside, here is a possibly useful suggestion :

1. Ask submitters to photograph their hands with a light source that is low and to one side, this will cast shadows across the shallow ridges in the hand to give you a better *input signal* of the lines of the hand.
2. Secondly use some kind of edge detection, or edge enhancement on the image's bitmap data. This can be implemented with a pretty standard [convolution matrix kernel filter](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-convmatrix.html), otherwise called a [Sobel operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator).
3. You might need to crop the image in to a region that is mostly just a square window on to the palm, unless the future is also written in the lines of the fingers.
4. Finally, to get lines and co-ordinates, you might need to look into image vectorization : [the Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) is particularly effective, but [vectorization algorithms from Microsoft Research](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/kopf/pixelart/index.html), [a survey paper from 2000](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-40953-X_2?LI=true#page-1), and ['Outliner', an open source edge finder and vectorizer](http://outliner.codeplex.com/) may also be of use.
   Using your **edge enhanced** image data, then turning this into a set of vectors with one of the methods described in those references will give you at least some mathematical formulas, and co-ordinates for the lines present. You could then divide the hand up into segments of interest and retrieve the formulas for lines that exist in those segments.
5. Matching formulas to their general shapes could be done with some kind of supervised machine learning, with examples of your shapes of interest being the training data for these.  You might also want to consider reducing the complexity of the formulas using the [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) as an additional step in this.

Hope this helps. By the way, if you get any useful heads ups about the future, be sure to let us know!

Comment: Thanks Cris, ll let u know once I have implemented every thing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example image?

It would probably involve [blurring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur) or [band-passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band-pass_filter) the image in order to retain only the relevant scale of contrasts (that is, blurring will remove lines and wrinkles that are too tiny, a band-pass will also eliminate features that are too large-scale).

After that, you can use the [Hough Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) to find the length and orientation of the lines in the image.

Alternatively, it might be a viable approach to detect line/wrinkle/darker areas and then [skeletonize](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/skeleton.htm) the image. This would give you the branch and end points of lines.